# Regular-grid-cluster plugin for Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins, grid-cluster

I am starting with Leaflet and I am trying to use the Regular-grid-cluster plugin with no success. The following code works until the definition of the 'const grid' element. So, I can see the markers on the map but I can not implement the functionality of the plugin. Could you point me the errors in the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Leaflet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <!-- Grid Cluster -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.RegularGridCluster/demo/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.RegularGridCluster/demo/zoomdisplay/zoomdisplay.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.RegularGridCluster/demo/demo.css" />
    <script src="https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.RegularGridCluster/demo/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.RegularGridCluster/demo/zoomdisplay/zoomdisplay.js"></script>
    <script src="https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.RegularGridCluster/dist/leaflet-regulargridcluster.src.js"></script>
    <script src="https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.RegularGridCluster/demo/random_data/main.js"></script>
    <!-- GeoJSON file -->
    <script src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1Wiju0Kfbpj2YKTKog1u2ZceEXBdbb12r"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 98vh; width: 100hw"></div>
    <script>
    var map = L.map('map');
    var CartoDB_PositronNoLabels = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);
    var CartoDB_PositronOnlyLabels = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);
    var southWest = L.latLng(-60, -80),
        northEast = L.latLng(-10, -60);
    var bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
    map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
    map.on('drag', function() {
        map.panInsideBounds(bounds, {
            animate: false
        });
    });
    var layer = L.geoJSON(points, {
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = "<p> <b>" + "FIC_ID: " + "</br>" + feature.properties.fic_id + "</b></br>" + "Región: " + "</br>" + feature.properties.reg_ejec + "</br>" + feature.properties.pro_ejec + ",</br> " + feature.properties.com_ejec + ",</br> " + feature.properties.num_informe + "</p>";
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
        }
    }).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
    const rules = {
        cells: {
            "fillColor": {
                "method": "mean",
                "attribute": "fic_id",
                "scale": "size",
                "range": ["#d7191c", "#fdae61", "#ffffbf", "#a6d96a", "#1a9641"]
            },
            "color": "black",
            "fillOpacity": 0.2,
            "weight": 0
        },
        markers: {
            "color": "white",
            "weight": 2,
            "fillOpacity": 0.9,
            "fillColor": {
                "method": "mean",
                "attribute": "fic_id",
                "scale": "continuous",
                "range": ["#ffffb2", "#fecc5c", "#fd8d3c", "#e31a1c"]
            },
            "radius": {
                "method": "count",
                "attribute": "fic_id",
                "scale": "continuous",
                "range": [7, 17]
            }
        },
        texts: {}
    }
    const grid = L.regularGridCluster({
        rules: rules,
        gridMode: 'hexagon,
        showCells: true,
        showMarkers: true,
        showTexts: false
    });
    grid.addLayers(layer);
    grid.addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: I made some amendments to the code, now I can see the markers when testing but I still got an error, this time the console says:

> leaflet-regulargridcluster.src.js:282 Uncaught TypeError:
> layersArray.map is not a function
> at i.addLayers (leaflet-regulargridcluster.src.js:282)
> at test05.html:94

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Leaflet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>
    
    <!-- Grid Cluster -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.RegularGridCluster/demo/zoomdisplay/zoomdisplay.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.RegularGridCluster/demo/demo.css" />

    <script src="https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.RegularGridCluster/demo/zoomdisplay/zoomdisplay.js"></script>
    <script src="https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.RegularGridCluster/dist/leaflet-regulargridcluster.src.js"></script>
    
    <!-- GeoJSON file -->
    <script src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1Wiju0Kfbpj2YKTKog1u2ZceEXBdbb12r"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 98vh; width: 100hw"></div>
    <script>
    var map = L.map('map');
    var CartoDB_PositronNoLabels = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);
    var CartoDB_PositronOnlyLabels = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 18,
    }).addTo(map);
    var southWest = L.latLng(-60, -80),
        northEast = L.latLng(-10, -60);
    var bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
    map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
    map.on('drag', function() {
        map.panInsideBounds(bounds, {
            animate: false
        });
    });
    var layer = L.geoJSON(points, {
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = "<p> <b>" + "FIC_ID: " + "</br>" + feature.properties.fic_id + "</b></br>" + "Región: " + "</br>" + feature.properties.region_ejecucion + "</br>" + feature.properties.provincia_ejecucion + ",</br> " + feature.properties.comuna_ejecucion + ",</br> " + feature.properties.numero + "</p>";
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
        }
    }).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
    const rules = {
        cells: {
            "fillColor": {
                "method": "mean",
                "attribute": "fic_id",
                "scale": "size",
                "range": ["#d7191c", "#fdae61", "#ffffbf", "#a6d96a", "#1a9641"]
            },
            "color": "black",
            "fillOpacity": 0.2,
            "weight": 0
        },
        markers: {
            "color": "white",
            "weight": 2,
            "fillOpacity": 0.9,
            "fillColor": {
                "method": "mean",
                "attribute": "fic_id",
                "scale": "continuous",
                "range": ["#ffffb2", "#fecc5c", "#fd8d3c", "#e31a1c"]
            },
            "radius": {
                "method": "count",
                "attribute": "fic_id",
                "scale": "continuous",
                "range": [7, 17]
            }
        },
        texts: {}
    }
    const grid = L.regularGridCluster({
        rules: rules,
        gridMode: 'square',
        showCells: true,
        showMarkers: true,
        showTexts: false
    });
    grid.addLayers(layer);
    grid.addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser debugger console?

Comment: I got two: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'grid' has already been declared' and 'leaflet.js:5 Uncaught Error: Map container not found.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation on Regular-grid-cluster Leaflet plugin is not very extensive, but with the help of demo code at https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.RegularGridCluster/demo/random_data/ I was able to make your code work.

First thing you notice in demo code is that input to `.addLayers` of `L.regularGridCluster` is not Leaflet layer, but an array of objects. Description of structure of these objects in the docs is not very helping, but in the demo code such object has the following form:

```
{marker: markerLayer,
 properties: {
   a: maxValue,
   b: minValue
 }
}
```

Next thing is that markers to be used in `L.regularGridCluster` must support styling, like for example `L.circleMarker`.

And the last thing, when creating markers from GeoJSON, this layer should not be added to the map, since marker display is regulated by `L.regularGridCluster`.

Taken all this into account, your code could then look something like this (`min` and `max` properties are created random, as in demo code):

```
var data = [];

var layer = L.geoJSON(points, {
    pointToLayer: function (point, latLng) {
      var marker = L.circleMarker(latLng, {radius: 10});
      return(marker);
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      const properties = {
          a: 5 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
          b: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
      };          
      data.push({marker: layer, properties: properties});
      var popupContent = "<p> <b>" + "FIC_ID: " + "</br>" + feature.properties.fic_id + "</b></br>" + "Región: " + "</br>" + feature.properties.reg_ejec + "</br>" + feature.properties.pro_ejec + ",</br> " + feature.properties.com_ejec + ",</br> " + feature.properties.num_informe + "</p>";
      layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }
});
map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());

const grid = L.regularGridCluster({
    rules: rules,
    gridMode: 'hexagon',
    showCells: true,
    showMarkers: true,
    showTexts: false
});
grid.addLayers(data);
grid.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you, with your code, I was able to run the script properly.